# Enable to insert data into SQL Server using a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying below code for inserting records into database via a stored procedure.

First time loop successfully insert record but after second time its shows me error on `ExecuteNonQuery`:

> Procedure or function SP_FUNCTIONAL_TITLE_MASTER_INSERT has too many arguments specified.

Please help.

```
public int InsertData(DataTable objLst)  
{
    string query = "SP_FUNCTIONAL_TITLE_MASTER_INSERT";

    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmdCommand = new SqlCommand(query, ConnectionClass.openConnection());

        foreach (DataRow dr in objLst.Rows)
        {
            cmdCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE",Convert.ToInt64( dr["Code"]));
            cmdCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", dr["Designation"]);
            cmdCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Group", dr["Group"]);

            cmdCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            IsSavedCount += 1;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        ConnectionClass.CloseConnection();
    }

    return IsSavedCount;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your sp code here too

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you're specifying too many parameters to the stored procedure.  Specify only the ones it needs.  (Note that you're adding the parameters *in a loop*, so for every row in `objLst` you add three parameters.  If there are 10 rows, does the stored procedure really have 30 parameters with repeated names?)

Comment: Yeah. Dear muhammed, can you read? Then READ THE DEFINITION OF THE SP. See what parameters it needs. Then realize that programming is not like having money. While you never can have too much money, you can have too many parameters.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would "fix it".

```
        foreach (DataRow dr in objLst.Rows)
        {
            cmdCommand.Parameters.Clear();
```

**But you'd be better off doing this**

(Create the parameters OUTSIDE the loop and SET the parameters INSIDE the loop)

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CODE", SqlDbType.BigInt)); /* fix to your datatype here */
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Designation", SqlDbType.VarChar, 128)); /* fix to your datatype and optional "size" here */
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Group", SqlDbType.VarChar, 128)); /* fix to your datatype and optional "size" here */

  foreach (DataRow dr in objLst.Rows)
  {
    command.Parameters["@CODE"].Value = Convert.ToInt64( dr["Code"]);
    command.Parameters["@Designation"].Value = dr["Designation"];
    command.Parameters["@Group"].Value = dr["Group"];
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

Comment: Correct but consider to create the parameters with the correct datatype. The first line _new SqlParamenter("@CODE", 0)_ is well known to be a source of troubles.

Comment: Good point.  I was using "pseudo code" from memory ... to write the answer.  But to OP, Steve is correct.  Create the correct-data-type-parameter from the get-go.